# display result of json data in textview of android

Tags: php, android, json

I am having one problem while displaying data in android app.This is my php.I have edited now to shorten the code.

```
if($imei_no!="" && $app_auid!="")
{
        //chk query
        $chk_query=$db1->query("select * from user where imei_number='$imei_no'");
        $chk_cnt=$chk_query->rowCount();
        if($chk_cnt>0)
        {
            $search_qry=$db1->query("select * from candidate_reception cr,candidate_counseling cc ,candidate_admission ca where cr.candidate_id=cc.candidate_id and cr.candidate_id=ca.candidate_id and cr.auid=ca.auid and cr.counseling_id=cc.counseling_id and cr.auid='$app_auid'");
            $ser_count=$search_qry->rowCount();
            if($ser_count>0)
            {
                $stud_row=$search_qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                $candidate_id=$stud_row->candidate_id;
                $auid = $stud_row->auid;
                $usn_no = $stud_row->usn_no;
                $sx = $stud_row->candidate_sex


                //image path    
                  if($inst_id==1){ $img_path = "1"; }
                  if($inst_id==2){ $img_path = "2"; }

                $result=array();    
                array_push($result, array('name' => $candidate_name,'img_path'=>$img_path));

            echo json_encode(array("can_data"=>$result));
            echo "Success"          
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Auid not Found.";
            }       
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Invalid IMEI Number.!!!";
        }
}
?>
```

and this is my java code:

```
  private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x/mobile_app/data_push.php";
    private EditText editTextUserName;
    private Button buttonLogin;

    TelephonyManager tel;
    TextView imei;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imei__val);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAUID);
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                login();
            }
        });

        tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        imei = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        imei.setText(tel.getDeviceId().toString());

    }

    private void login(){
        String username = editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        String imei_no = imei.getText().toString().trim();
        userLogin(username,imei_no);
    }

    private void userLogin(final String username,final String imei_no){
        class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(IMEI_Val.this,"Please Wait",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                if(s=="Success"){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(IMEI_Val.this, CapturePhoto.class);
                   // intent.putExtra(USER_NAME,username);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

               else{
                   Toast.makeText(IMEI_Val.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("Tag Name", "Log Message");
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("auid",params[0]);
                data.put("imei",params[1]);
                RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();
                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGIN_URL,data);
                return result;
            }
        }
        UserLoginClass ulc = new UserLoginClass();
        ulc.execute(username,imei_no);
    }

}
```

My problem is when am clicking on Login button, am getting json result in toast with student details after valid user inputs.I want to goto next activity if the the user inputs are valid and display other details like name,college etc.How can I do that?
Here am getting json result as response when I enter valid inputs.I could not go to next activity and display other details in text box even though am entering correct regno.

Comment: @ user6588225 what json response your getting ?? show what your getting inside Toast message

Comment: This is the message in the toast: {"can_data":[{"name":"dfsdfd","address":"gdgfsdf","course":"dfdfdsf"}]} Success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user6588225

so your sending Json with Success message

so rather than using `==` try to use `contains`

so inside your `onPostExecute(String s)`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
     super.onPostExecute(s);
     loading.dismiss();
     if(s.contains("Success")){
         Intent intent = new Intent(IMEI_Val.this, CapturePhoto.class);
         // intent.putExtra(USER_NAME,username);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
     else{
       Toast.makeText(IMEI_Val.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Log.d("Tag Name", "Log Message");
     }
}
```

Comment: Got it.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user6588225 you might have got this but now you have to decode your json and pass those decoded value to next activity

Comment: Yes.How can I do that. Now am trying for that only.Can you please help me atleast to display one data.

Comment: @user6588225 check Farhan answer and try to send you json data in that format from your PHP then I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @ eLemEnt Can you suggest some link to do this?

Answer (score 0):

use if("Success".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) insted of  if(s=="Success")

Comment: You are getting "Success" as the value  in variable s. Right ?

Comment: can u post the screenshot of what you are getting in the toast

Comment: This is same like if the registered user enters his his information like username and password in login page,then go to next activity and display all the details of that user after validation.How to do that using php and android

Comment: After entering valid information , else part is executing.

Comment: @user6588225 dude its because even if your entering valid details your sending "Success" as well as some key value array from your php file that is why only "Success" is not getting matched. Please post what your getting inside Toast message

Comment: @eLemEnt This is the message in the toast: {"can_data":[{"name":"dfsdfd","address":"gdgfsdf","course":"dfdfdsf"}]} Success

Answer (score 0):

change your response in php to this

```
echo json_encode(array("can_data"=>$result,"success"=>"1"));
```

at android side parse it as

```
JsonObject responseObject = new JsonObject(responseString);
String success=responseObject.getString("success");
if(success.equals("1")){
// go to next activity
}
```