# Display Student details in text view after validation in android

Tags: php, android, json

This is my previous question: [display result of json data in textview of android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633796/display-result-of-json-data-in-textview-of-android)

And this is json result:

```
{"can_data":[{"name":"dfsdfd","address":"gdgfsdf","course":"dfdfdsf"}]}
```

I want to display this details in text view of DetailsActivity.java after validating user input IMEI_Val.java class. How can I do this.Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please, show us what you've tried. And add some details about those classes.

Comment: It is there in my previous question.I added a link here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633796/display-result-of-json-data-in-textview-of-android    Now I want to display name,address etc in my next activity.How to do that.

Comment: You can use gson library for Json parsing.

go to below link


https://guides.codepath.com/android/Leveraging-the-Gson-Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse the above json then here it is.

Send the response as putExtra to your IMEI_Val.java activityClass.

To fetch the details,

```
                    try {
                        JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(jsonObject);
                        JSONArray canData = responseObject.getJSONArray("can_data");
                        JSONObject canDataJSONObject = canData.getJSONObject(0);
                        String name = canDataJSONObject.getString("name");
                        String address = canDataJSONObject.getString("address");
                        String course = canDataJSONObject.getString("course");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

You can set it to your text view now.

Comment: I am trying this code. Getting error in jsonObject.

Comment: @user6588225 - In your previous question, you have `String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGIN_URL,data);` that result is your jsonObject here