# Display Json result in another activity after valid user inputs

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to get data from json and display it in textview in android.This is my previous question:[Display Student details in text view after validation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652734/display-student-details-in-text-view-after-validation-in-android) Here is my code in IMEI_Val.java:

```
 @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(IMEI_Val.this,"Please Wait",null,true,true);
            }
     @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    loading.dismiss();
                    if(s.contains("Success")){
                        Intent i = new Intent(IMEI_Val.this, CapturePhoto.class);
                        try {

                            JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject();
                            JSONArray canData = responseObject.getJSONArray("can_data");
                            JSONObject canDataJSONObject = canData.getJSONObject(0);
                            String name = canDataJSONObject.getString("name");
                            String father_name = canDataJSONObject.getString("father_name");
                            String sex = canDataJSONObject.getString("sex");
                            i.putExtra("name",name);
                            i.putExtra("father_name",father_name);
                            i.putExtra("sex",sex);
                            startActivity(i);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                   else{
                       Toast.makeText(IMEI_Val.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("Tag Name", "Log Message");
                    }
                }
```

And this is my another activity where I want to display details:

```
 private void getData() {
        textNameVal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textNameVal);
        textYearVal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textYearVal);
        String name =  getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        String father_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("father_name");
        String sex = getIntent().getStringExtra("sex");

        textNameVal.setText("Candidate Name:\t" + name);
       textYearVal.setText("SEX:\t" + sex);
        textParentVal.setText("Father's NAme:\t" + father_name);


    }
```

When I run this code,if I enter valid inputs it is not going to CapturePhoto.class. Can anyone help me to resolve.For the wrong input it is displaying a message that "doesn't exist" in toast.But for the valid inputs,its is showing just a dialogue as "please wait" and doesn't going to next activity.

Comment: Try changing `JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject();` to `JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(s);`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference                                                                                    at com.example.user.studenttechweb.CapturePhoto.getData(CapturePhoto.java:218)        I got this error if I put this.

Comment: You did not initialize `textParentVal` in your second activity.

Comment: I got it.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onPostExecute would throw JSONExeption

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                if(s.contains("Success")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(IMEI_Val.this, CapturePhoto.class);
                    try {

                        JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject();
                        JSONArray canData = responseObject.getJSONArray("can_data");
                        JSONObject canDataJSONObject = canData.getJSONObject(0);
                        String name = canDataJSONObject.getString("name");
                        String father_name = canDataJSONObject.getString("father_name");
                        String sex = canDataJSONObject.getString("sex");
                        i.putExtra("name",name);
                        i.putExtra("father_name",father_name);
                        i.putExtra("sex",sex);
                        startActivity(i);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
               else{
                   Toast.makeText(IMEI_Val.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("Tag Name", "Log Message");
                }
            }
```

`responseObject=new JSONObject();`

creates a new empty object but need

`responseObject=new JSONObject(s);`

and then it will have values from response.

Answer (score -1):

try to put intent inside try {} block

Comment: I got this exeption:   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.example.user.studenttechweb.CapturePhoto.getData(CapturePhoto.java:218)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.studenttechweb.CapturePhoto.onCreate(CapturePhoto.java:69)

Comment: name ,father name and sex are found in first activity can u log this??